# Cambiar version de php en HomeStead

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema con el phpmyadmin en  HomeStead me lanza un error de 502 bad Gateway, he estado investigando y lei que ese problema usualmente ocurre cuando mi VM y mi HomeStead no estan usando la misma version de php. Actualmente estoy usando la version de php 7.2.4. He intentado cambiar la version de php de HomeStead pero en las opciones no me muestra la version 7.2.4 que es la que quiero asignar para que tengan la misma version de php. Si alguien sabe alguna posible solucion se lo agradeceria mucho. Gracias de antemano.

A continuacion le dejare una foto de las versiones que si me deja seleccionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Utiliza adminer y evitas todo esto con phpmyadmin.

Comment: Hola amigo, adminer hace la misma funcion que phpmyadmin?

Comment: Puedes leer en internet lo que hace...

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo hare.